# Is is possible to pretty print a JSON log message in ElasticSearch/Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I have logs being indexed by ElasticSearch from stdout of our application server. Without having to modify the source writing the logs, is it possible to "pretty print" any JSON log message? If I try to pretty-print the JSON from my logger, each line is logged as a separate entry in ES.

If I don't, I have this message shown in our Kibana/OpenSearch Dashboard as follows:

[image]

We're using the latest AWS OpenSearch 1.1.